# Can I change my default meeting start time in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

tl;dr

How can I get Google Calendar to create events at `xx:05` instead of `xx:00` by default?

People are weird.

My senior leadership is encouraging us to start meetings in our calendars at 5 minutes after the hour (or half hour). Is there a way, using some combination of a Chrome Extension, Google Workspace App, eldritch invocation, dark pact, forbidden technology, or similar, that will, when I create an event by selecting the time block, have the field default to five minutes after the half hour or hour?

I searched the Chrome store and found no such extensions - I searched the Workspace Store and found no such apps. I didn't see any relevant settings in Google Calendar settings (though I do love Speedy Meetings for an adjacent reason). Are there shenanigans I could be employing via Google Apps Script or my own Chrome Extension that would permit this behavior?

Relevant to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/411962/is-there-a-way-to-automate-xx05-as-the-meeting-start-and-xx55-as-the-meeting-e) from SuperUser.

Comment: Since people seem to appreciate the question, I went digging, and would recommend that folks upvote [this thread](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/102623919) in Google's Calendar support.